# Is there an option to split a webview which is contributed to a panel in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

I created an extension in VSCode where I contributed a webview to a panel. Is it somehow possible to give the user the opportunity to split the webview in order to have multiple instances of the webview next to each other in the panel? It should work as in the integrated terminal of VSCode. A picture of the expecting result is below:

[splitted terminals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/150sQ.png)

If it is not possible, is there any other way to contribute a custom view and allow the user to split the view?

Thanks in advance.